# Make a client-side null collection reactive in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have a null collection that I'd like to make reactive on the client side only. Currently, the null collection is copied from a server-side collection when a template is rendered. The template then serves up data from the null collection. A user clicks a button and a meteor method is called to update the server-side collection. I'd like for the null collection to get updated so that it will show another set of images right after the user clicks - but because it isn't reactive that doesn't happen.  I tried using the deps functionality but I'm lost.

Here is my client-side code:

```
var tempCovers = new Meteor.Collection(null);
var coversDep = new Deps.Dependency;

var getCovers = function(){
    coversDep.depend();
    console.log("covers gotten");
    return tempCovers;
}

var setCovers = function(comic){
    tempCovers.update({_id: comic._id}, {$inc: {score:1}});
    coversDep.changed();
    console.log("covers set");
}

Template.covers.rendered = function(){
    covers = Covers.find().fetch();
    tempCovers.insert(covers);
}

Template.covers.events({
    'click .comic-cover': function(e){
        var title = $(e.target).data('title');
        comic = Covers.findOne({title: title});
        setCovers(comic);

        Meteor.call('vote', title, function(error,id){
            clearErrors(); 
            if(error){
                throwError(error.reason, 'error');
            } else {
                throwError('Voted!', 'success');
                Router.go('/');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out in case anybody wants to know how it's done.

Here's a look at my template so the answer makes more sense:

```
<template name="covers">
    <h3 class="centered">Which Cover Do You Prefer?</h3>
    <div class="covers wrapper">
    {{#each cover}}
        <div class="comic-wrapper pure-u-1-2 centered" data-title="{{title}}">
            <a href="#" class="comic-cover" data-title="{{title}}"><img src="{{thumbnail.path}}/portrait_uncanny.{{thumbnail.extension}}" alt="{{title}}" data-title="{{title}}"/></a>
            <h5 class="centered">{{title}}</h5>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

I had to create a Template helper that returns a call to the getCovers function. The getCovers function looks like this:

```
var getCovers = function(){

    //set the dependency
    coversDep.depend();

    var arrayCovers = tempCovers.find().fetch();

    //get 2 random objects from arrayCovers
    var sampledCovers = _.sample(arrayCovers[0],2);

    return sampledCovers;
}
```

This will get my 2 random objects and return them to the template helper, which will then be sent to the template.

Laslty, I had to call setCovers when a click event is fired to trigger the dependency change.

```
var setCovers = function(comic){
    coversDep.changed();
}

Template.covers.events({
    'click .comic-cover': function(e){
        var title = $(e.target).data('title');

        //make a call to show that the reactive data source has changed
        setCovers();

        Meteor.call('vote', title, function(error,id){
            clearErrors(); 
            if(error){
                throwError(error.reason, 'error');
            } else {
                throwError('Voted!', 'success');
                Router.go('/');
            }
        })
    }
});
```